# Best way to conduct and present simulation results of nonparametric density estimation

Tags: data-visualization, nonparametric, nonparametric-density

I am conducting a procedure where I first estimate some auxiliary functions (nonparametrically using kernels) and then, knowing their relations to the densities of interest, I use these auxiliary nonparametric estimators to construct a nonparametric estimator of the density of interest.

I want to conduct simulations (say, 500 simulations) to show that my method works and to display simulation results graphically. In each simulation I draw 1000 observations.

What is the best way to present the results and convince people that method works well that?

Should I construct the estimator of interest per each simulation and then display the pointwise average of that across simulations? Or should it be the pointwise median across simulations? Should I also display the 2.5% and 97.5% pointwise percentiles obtained in simulations?

Comment: Would you add some specifics as to what is meant by "knowing their relations to the densities of interest"?  Also, do you mean "probability density functions" when you say "densities" ?

Comment: @JimB Yes, when I say "densities", I mean probability density functions. I have a nonlinear relationship $f=\phi(w)$, where both $f$ and $w$ are pdfs. $w$ can be directly estimated from that data and then since $\phi$ is known I can estimate $f$ as well.